# Why doesnot the index route changes not work?

Tags: node.js, express, express-generator

I created a new app using the express generator without any view engine. I go to http://127.0.0.1:3000 which shows the standard express welcome view. Then I add some query params to url like http://127.0.0.1:3000/?test1=testing&test2=testing234 and try to access these in the indexRouter's index.js but cannot access the query params. I tried

```
req.query.test1
```

and all other variants nothing works. Then I commented the line

```
app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

but I still can access the welcome screen. Commenting the below line throws error which i think is how it works as it is serving a static file.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Is there any way I can access the query params in the home url in index router? What am I missing here?

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

**indexRouter**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req, 'request');
    console.log(res, 'response');
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What does `req.query.test1` printed??

Comment: it doesnot print  anything. i tried logging but execution doesnot even reach the indexRouter.

Comment: Can you post your `indexRouter `??

Comment: Show us your full routing code.

Comment: Added app.js and indexRouter. Actually its the basic express generator. No change has been done.

Comment: @Sp0T you have to uncomment this line `app.use('/', indexRouter);` in app.js, otherwise the route is not reachable.

Comment: commeting uncommeting doesnot work. even with comment the welcome screen still works.

Comment: @Sp0T If you want to do smoothed with `/` router you should have that in your `app.js`. May be express is serving that page by default, so you are getting that page even after commenting that line.

Comment: tried doing that. doesnot work @Subburaj

Comment: @Sp0T Whether it reached the router??

Comment: @Subburaj nope. still not seeing anything in console. no logs. other routes except for the home/index route works fine. can access the query params but not in the index route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the req params by commenting out

`// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

And, change the response method
Instead of rendering the static file

`// res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
res.send('something');`

Comment: Hey thanks. this works. any idea why. also what if i have to respond with view file? res.sendFile does not work even with root defined..

Comment: You will have to use at least one view engine(ejs, pug, ...) to renders dynamically. --no-view is not supposed to be rendered with dynamic views.